# Maven like file exclude, include in SBT

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, pom.xml, sbt-assembly

look for solution in scala build.sbt to exclude the classes under the path for all dependency except three artifact.

similar to what pom.xml does here.

````
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>com.org.abc:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>io.foo:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>io.boo:*</artifact>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </filter>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>javax/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>servletx/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you have detailed packaging requirements the best solution is the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/) plugin, which allows you to create quite complex builds.

If you are just wanting to exclude some dependencies (which looks like it might be the case here), you can at the `provided` configuration to your dependency declaration in the `build.sbt` file which will exclude those jars from being packaged. For example:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3" % "provided"
```

indicates that you expect the client to provide the dependency when they run the application.